# How do I collapse a machine's Time Machine snapshots to just the final one?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I want to drop all but the latest snapshot from several retired machines' Time Machine store. The computers are no longer in active use, so being able to go back in time a few months ago from their last used date of a few years ago is not useful. I just need the final snapshot.

Additional info:

- Returning to the original machine to just image the drive is not an option.
- My Time Machine volume is just an external hard drive that I've had connected to several machines over time, so it's got a single Backups.backupd backup store with multiple machine directories therein.
- I don't see it as a requirement that the snapshot stay in Time Machine format. I just have files that I want to be able to dig out of the old machines' files sometimes, and hanging onto the Time Machine backups has let me do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Time Machine uses filesystem hardlinks to deduplicate unmodified files across snapshots](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2007/10/mac-os-x-10-5/14/#time-machine-internals).

Therefore, to collapse/flatten all prior snapshots down to the most recent snapshot, simply delete the older date-stamped folders in Finder, leaving only the most recent snapshot.

**Word of caution**: be absolutely sure you're comfortable with the state of the most recent snapshot *before* you delete older snapshots.

If files existed at time-point A and B but not C. Removing A and B *will* permanently remove the files that do not exist in C.

Finally, if you're using an encrypted sparse bundle, you should compact the sparse bundle using `hdiutil` in order to free newly unused space.

```
$ sudo hdiutil compact /path/to/disk-image
Starting to compact…
Reclaiming free space…
...
Finishing compaction…
Reclaimed 11.2 GB out of 118.7 GB possible.
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a great solution. My solution at the time was "don't do that" – I instead used CarbonCopyCloner (as it still had a version that would run on a Powerbook G4) to make a system image, then deleted the Time Machine backups entirely.